# Curvature of a graph.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Find the curvature of $r(t)=\langle 2\sin(t),\cos (3t),t\rangle$ at $t=\pi/3$ and $t=\pi/2$.

I know you have to find the arc length parametrization, but I am still not too sure how how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a formula that avoids parametrization by arc-length. Ugly, but sometimes we have to suck it up: $$\kappa_{{\bf r}}(t) = \frac{\|{\bf r}'(t) \times {\bf r}''(t)\|}{\|{\bf r}'(t)\|^3}.$$Have fun computing derivatives. You can see a proof of that formula in John Oprea's Differential Geometry and Its Applications, in page $30$, for example (it is not hard, the only thing annoying about it is that the chain rule keeps spanning more and more $\|{\bf r}'(t)\|$'s).